# Read a Date value form Excel File

Tags: scala

I am trying to read a Excel File which is having Date column. I want to validate it but while validating date type field this method is not working. I tried with text file and it's working. As per my observation the excel file by default save date value as date type not string. but i am trying to parse (string type). But i don't know how to read excel column as string.

I tried to read it to read getCell value directly but it is not working for me.

```
java.time.LocalDate.parse(row.getCell(2) , java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT))
```

```
val DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy"

  def validateDf(row: Row): Boolean = try {
    //assume row.getString(1) with give Datetime string
    java.time.LocalDate.parse(row.getString(2) , java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT))
    java.time.LocalDate.parse(row.getString(3) , java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT))
    true
  } catch {
    case ex: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException => {
      // Handle exception if you want
      println("Exception : " + ex)
      false
    }
  }
val validDf = sample1.filter(validateDf(_))
val inValidDf = sample1.except(validDf)
```

````
Input Excel Data
-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|AirName|Place|TakeoffDate|arriveoffDate|
+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|  Delta|  Aus|  12/6/2015|    11/6/2015|
|  Delta|     |  12/6/2016|    01/6/2016|
| Vistra|  New|  11/6/2017|    04/6/2017|
|  Delta|  Aus|  10/6/2018|    04/6/2018|
| JetAir|  Aus|  14/6/2019|    04/6/2019|
+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+

Expected valid Data(Based on Valid and Invalid date)
-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|AirName|Place|TakeoffDate|arriveoffDate|
+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|  Delta|  Aus|  12/6/2015|    11/6/2015|
|  Delta|     |  12/6/2016|    01/6/2016|
| Vistra|  New|  11/6/2017|    04/6/2017|
|  Delta|  Aus|  10/6/2018|    04/6/2018|
+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
Expected Invalid Data
-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|AirName|Place|TakeoffDate|arriveoffDate|
+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
|  Delta|  Aus|  14/6/2019|    04/6/2018|
+-------+-----+-----------+-------------+
```
````

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/) for reading data from excel files.
You can implement it like this:

```
val DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy"
val currentCell = row.getString(1)
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(currentCell)) {
   try {

     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
     val cellValue = sdf.format(currentCell.getDateCellValue())

   } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not working for me it is giving error. <console>:11: error: ';' expected but '=' found.
     cellValue: Date = sdf.format(currentCell.getDateCellValue());

Comment: I tried to implement this in databricks notebook but it still throwing error.notebook:2: error: not found: value row
val currentCell = row.getString(1)
                  ^
notebook:3: error: not found: value DateUtil
if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(currentCell)) {
    ^
notebook:6: error: not found: value SimpleDateFormat
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
     ^
notebook:7: error: not found: value sdf
     val cellValue = sdf.format(currentCell.getDateCellValue())
                     ^

Comment: Looks like you need to import the relevant packages of simpledateformat and dateutils

Comment: notebook:7: error: not found: value sdf
     val cellValue = sdf.format(currentCell.getDateCellValue())
                     ^
notebook:9: error: not found: value ParseException
   } catch (ParseException e) {
            ^
notebook:10: error: not found: value e
        e.printStackTrace()
        ^  Even i have imported respective library import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter

Comment: which Package you are taking about.

Comment: I imported import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Calendar, Date}


object DateUtil {

  private val dateFmt = "MM-dd-yyyy"

  def today(): String = {
    val date = new Date
    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFmt)
    sdf.format(date)
  }} but not getting solution.

Comment: Here anyone can help me.

Comment: look at this snippet of the code you wrote in your last comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WYqz8AiqSQ24w8NMAJpIqQ.  so, if `currentCell` is a `Row`, and `currentCell.getDateCellValue()` returns `Date` object successfully, it should work